# Solution verification of a series with integer part

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I want to study $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \bigg\lfloor{\frac{n+2}{n^2}}\bigg\rfloor$.
I have thought to apply the leibniz criterion but first of all I have to remark that:

1. $a_n=\lfloor{\frac{n+2}{n^2}}\rfloor\to 0$\
2. $a_n>0$
3. $a_n$ decreasing

For the last point I have considered that:
$$\bigg\lfloor{\frac{n+2}{n^2}}\bigg\rfloor=\bigg\lfloor{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}\bigg\rfloor\geq \bigg\lfloor{\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{2}{(n+1)^2}}\bigg\rfloor\,\, \forall n\geq 1$$
So this implies the decrease of $a_n$ and then the series converges.

> Is my attempt correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $(-1)^n\left\lfloor\frac{n+2}{n^2}\right\rfloor=0$ when $n>2$, your series converge.

But, yes, your approach is correct.

Comment: But the fact that the general term of the series goes to $0$ is only a necessary condition, not?

Comment: Yes. But when **all** but finitely many terms are **equal** to $0$, then it is trivial that the series converges.

Comment: Ah sorry I thought you were referring to the limit!

Comment: I wrote that $(-1)^n\left\lfloor\frac{n+2}{n^2}\right\rfloor=0$ when $n>2$, not that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\left\lfloor\frac{n+2}{n^2}\right\rfloor=0$.

Comment: Yes Yes my fault